# How calculate the mean each 12 rows?

Tags: r

I have a txt file with one column

```
data=structure(list(V3 = c(1:120)), row.names = c(NA,120L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to compute the mean like this

```
 first 12 rows    >>  first value
 following 12 rows   >> second value
 etcs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> colMeans(matrix(unlist(data), 12))
 [1]   6.5  18.5  30.5  42.5  54.5  66.5  78.5  90.5 102.5 114.5
```

and benchmark with some of its variants

```
microbenchmark(
  f1 = colMeans(matrix(unlist(data), 12)),
  f2 = colMeans(matrix(data[[1L]], 12)),
  f3 = colMeans(matrix(unlist(data, use.names = FALSE), 12)),
  unit = "relative"
)
```

showing

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f1 4.166667 3.896226 3.729477 3.818182 3.652542 4.134752   100
   f2 1.437500 1.433962 1.475840 1.436364 1.440678 3.886525   100
   f3 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

Comment: Very fast but would be faster with `data[[1L]]` or `use.names=FALSE` in `unlist()`?

Comment: @s_baldur yes, that would be faster

Answer (score 4):

```
aggregate(data$V3, list(group = 0:(nrow(data)-1) %/% 12), mean)

#    group     x
# 1      0   6.5
# 2      1  18.5
# 3      2  30.5
# 4      3  42.5
# 5      4  54.5
# 6      5  66.5
# 7      6  78.5
# 8      7  90.5
# 9      8 102.5
# 10     9 114.5
```